# C programming with structures and functions

Tags: c, setter, getter

I have a simple exercise here. I have created the following structure in structure.c:

```
struct student {
    char *first;
    char *last;
    string name;
    int id;
    double GPA;
};
```

I need to come up with the following functions and define it in the same file:

```
setName(char* name[size])

getName()

setID()

setGPA(double GPA)

getGPA()
```

I don't understand how I'm suppose to create setters and getters if structures haven't been initialized yet. I'm guessing I use pointers but I am unsure of how to do so in C.

And then I'm supposed to declare/list all these functions in the header file, which I am also quite confused about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a poitner to the structure to each setter/getter function, for example

```
void
student_set_first_name(struct student *student, const char *const name)
 {
    size_t length;
    if ((student == NULL) || (name == NULL))
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid parameters for `%s()'\n"), __FUNCTION__);
        return;
     }
    /* In case we are overwriting the field, free it before 
     * if it's NULL, nothing will happen. You should try to
     * always initialize the structure fields, to prevent
     * undefined behavior.
     */
    free(student->first);

    length = strlen(name);
    student->first = malloc(1 + length);
    if (student->name == NULL)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error in `%s()'\n"), __FUNCTION__);
        return;
     }
    memcpy(student->first, name, 1 + length);
 }

 const char *
 student_get_first_name(struct student *student)
  {
     if (student == NULL)
         return NULL;
     return student->first;
  }
```

And you could use the function like this

```
struct student student;
const char    *first_name;

memset(&student, 0, sizeof(student));
student_set_first_name(&student, "My Name");
first_name = student_get_first_name(&student);
if (first_name != NULL)
    fprintf(stdout, "First Name: %s\n", first_name);
/* work with `student', and when you finish */
free(student.first);
/* and all other `malloc'ed stuff */
```

The good thing is that you could hide the structure definition from the library user and prevent them from misusing the structre, like setting invalid values and other things.

Comment: Great post thank you that clarified things greatly. I am still confused as to what I should do in the header file as it pertains to enlisting the fucntion in it.. Any help?

Comment: Search google about forward declarations, just provide one for the `struct` and a prototype for each function, there are some other posts on SO about the topic, one of which is mine.